# Text is wrapping around my left navigation menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a menu. I want text to the right of it but I still want the mobile to be 100% width. When it's on desktop, how do I make the column not wrap around the div? I could make this 100% height, but then on mobile it might not work.

jsfiddle.net/La909cq3
Notice that name goes to the right of the menu if you stretch the container to be desktop width.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="manage.newPerson"><b>Groups of People</b></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="manage.newPerson"><b>Make a New Person</b></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="manage.people"><b>Make a New Manager</b></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you put together a fiddle of what you have now?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/La909cq3/ You'll notice "name" is to the right of the menu, but everything else is under the menu (You might have to stretch the width to see the responsive effect)

Answer (score 0):

I just put `clear:both;` on your div that wraps around the form. Once i did that your 'name' heading stop floating up to the right of your list of items.

https://jsfiddle.net/6beL3rn5/

Comment: Thanks for your support. Now when the menu is full screen, it's no longer to the left as a navigation bar. It's full screen both mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

It really only has to do with the fact that the menu and the form need to be in separate grid spaces. you have the menu wrapped in col-md-4 which will flowt ot to the left...but no grid class for the div around the form. Doing this will help that

Look at how I added an outer div with

```
<div class="row">
```

and the added the col-md-12 class to both the menu and the form divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbn4hnw1/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put col-md-4 around the second div http://jsfiddle.net/La909cq3/1/

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `word-wrap` in `CSS`?

Try this, I find it works well for me.

```
word-wrap: break-word; 
white-space:normal;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: I tried word wrap and it's still behaving the same. What I'm trying to do is make a vertical list for mobile instead of horizontal (the nav bar shrinks in to horizontal, I want the vertical list to just behave like col-md-4) http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_vertical_responsive

Comment: This has the basics of what you need. http://www.menucool.com/ddmenu/create-mobile-friendly-responsive-menu